# std::any automatic casting function

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

So far i have to add everything in.

```
template<typename T>
T my_any_cast(const std::any* Any) {
    const std::type_info& Typeid = Any->type();
    if (Typeid == typeid(int))
        return static_cast<T>(*std::any_cast<int>(Any));
    else if (Typeid == typeid(long))
        return static_cast<T>(*std::any_cast<long>(Any));
    else if (Typeid == typeid(std::string))
        return static_cast<T>(*std::any_cast<std::string>(Any));
}
```

Comment: Yes, use `std::variant` together with `std::visit`. Also enable your compiler warnings, so you'll be able to catch bugs like the above, which pretty much [guarantees making demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) due to undefined behavior when the whole thing fall through and does not return anything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you have a example of `std::variant` i didnt know about it

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do what you're trying to do.

As pointed out in the comments I think using `std::variant` is a better solution than `std::any`. It provides better mechanisms for detecting the contained type.

I suggest you read about `std::variant` [here](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/variant.html)

Below is a quick demonstration of using an `std::variant` which is a type safe union.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct Visitor
{
    void operator( )( int value ) { std::cout << "Visitor: Holds an int " << value << '\n'; }
    void operator( )( double value ) { std::cout << "Visitor: Holds a double " << value << '\n'; }
    void operator( )( long value ) { std::cout << "Visitor: Holds a long " << value << '\n'; }
};


int main( )
{
    // Can hold any type and any number of types.
    using types = std::variant<int, double, long>;

    // Initialize the variant with a long.
    types t{ 10L };

    // Test to see which type is active in the variant.
    if ( std::holds_alternative<long>( t ) )
        std::cout << "Holds a long\n";

    // Attempt to get the active type from the variant.
    // If the active type does not match the requested
    // type a nullptr is returned.
    if ( auto value{ std::get_if<double>( &t ) }; !value )
        std::cout << "Not a double\n";

    // Change what type the variant holds on the fly.
    t = 14;
    if ( auto value{ std::get_if<int>( &t ) } )
        std::cout << "It's a int now\n";

    // Asking for a type that is not the currently
    // active type in the variant throws a 
    // std::bad_variant_access exception when using
    // std::get instead of std::get_if.
    // auto value{ std::get<double>( t ) };

    // Use the visitor defined above to call a function over
    // the currently active type in the variant.
    std::visit( Visitor{ }, t );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, bull looking at it, i really need to use std::any in what im doing